Trying to configure Gedmo soft delete
I am trying to make doctrine.yaml include Gedmo soft delete. This is my configuration:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '16'

        profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
        use_savepoints: true
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
        report_fields_where_declared: true
        validate_xml_mapping: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
        mappings:
            translatable:
                type: attribute # or annotation or xml
                alias: Gedmo
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                # make sure vendor library location is correct
                dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/Translatable/Entity"
            Gedmo:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/src/SoftDeleteable'
                alias: Gedmo
                is_bundle: false
            App:
                type: attribute
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        controller_resolver:
            auto_mapping: false

when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
            dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            proxy_dir: '%kernel.build_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system

When I run command php bin/console cache:clear I am getting following error:
Can only configure "xml", "yml", "php", "staticphp" or "attribute" through the DoctrineBundle. Use your own bundle to configure other metadata drivers. You can register them by adding a new driver to the "doctrine.orm.default_metadata_driver" service definition.   

I checked the composer, all the libraries are installed. What am I doing wrong here?

It seems unlikely you would be using annotation for one library and attribute for another.

Also, the doctrine.orm.mappings.Gedmo definitions are not needed at all, since the bundle doesn't provide its own entities for softdeletable.
